# Apache Camel logging to dedicated directory for each route in XML DSL

Tags: logging, routes, apache-camel

How to define logging for each Apache Camel route into separate dedicated directory/folder in XML DSL? We would like to remain existing logger.
Thanks a lot for clear and exhaustive respose with examples at least for three routes.
Mykola

A lot of articles were read. No exhaustive explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would try to do:

1. use the Log component in your routes
2. each log should use a custom logger class that you define. The "loggerRef" property links the "log" component to the logger class.

See these https://camel.apache.org/components/4.0.x/eips/log-eip.html#_using_custom_logger

3. Define your custom logger class. In it you should get the route id, use it to make a path (example: "/logs/<route_id>.log"), open this file and append text in it.